# Is there a way to restart RDS and EC2 instances on CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I've recently started using CDK and I have little programming experience.

I've managed to set up an environment with a basic EC2 instance, a VPC with 2 subnets and an RDS instance. I've also created some CloudWatch Alarms for CPU usage of the RDS DB, for example:

```
      const CPUUsage = new cw.Alarm(this, 'CPUUsage', {
        metric: cpuUsage, //imported from another stack where I created the DB
        threshold: 4,
        evaluationPeriods: 2,
        alarmName: 'DB CPU Usage',
      });
```

I want to create an alarm where if the CPU of an instance (one alarm for EC2 and another for RDS) goes over an % (4 in this case) it would restart.

So far I haven't found anything that would restart the RDS instance, and for the EC2 instance I've only found the [InitCommand class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.InitCommand.html) which doesn't really fit my needs, as I don't want to use shell commands in the code (if there's no other way it has to be done that way I guess).

Thank you in advance for any help given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you supply a metric that is a built-in per-instance metric, or any metric with an `InstanceId` dimension that contains a valid instance ID, you can use the [`EC2Action` alarm action:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch_actions.Ec2Action.html)

```
alarm.addAlarmAction(
  new actions.Ec2Action(actions.Ec2InstanceAction.REBOOT),
);
```

Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html

Answer (score -1):

CDK does not do anything in the cloud directly. The only thing the CDK library does is synth the Cloudformation template. When you use `cdk deploy` it sends that synthed template to Cloudformation to run.

If you need functionality to occur during or after deployment, you are better served by a combination of CodePipeline and custom resources to check for certain situations and act accordingly.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer.

I meant as adding an action to a cloudwatch alarm (e.g.: if CPU is higher then 5% , restart instance). Is that still true in this case?

Comment: mmm im not familiar enough with what alarms and Cloudwatch Events are possible with ec2 -  If you can restart an EC2 instance through the AWSCLI you can probably do it through a cloudwatch event as well.

It may be however that you need to have the alarm trigger off the cpu metric, and send a cloudwatch event to a lambda that will perform the SDK commands to restart the ec2.